# IllegalStateException when using a custom SQLFunctionTemplate

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am attempting to register function within Hibernate so that I can preform a coalesce within a count statement on a Oracle database. As there seems to very little in the way of examples in how to use this Hibernate feature, I have drawn from the small examples I have found on different forums

The application server starts with out issue and the log indicates that it is using the new dialect class.

```
13:59:59,177 INFO  [Dialect] Using dialect: org.myprograms.ece.pi.CustomECEOracle10gDialect
```

However, when I attempt to execute the query using the new function I receive the following exception.

Now, I am not sure if I am using the regiesterFunction() in the correct manner or even if there is a better way to preform the count(coalesce(x,y)). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
14:01:20,903 SEVERE [application] java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1652)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxy.createQuery(EntityManagerProxy.java:81)
    at org.myprograms.ece.AdminDataLoadValidator.refreshDiscreteVariableValues(AdminDataLoadValidator.java:437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataLoadValidator_$$_javassist_seam_16.refreshDiscreteVariableValues(AdminDataLoadValidator_$$_javassist_seam_16.java)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataFileLoaderBean.viewDiscreteVariableBreakdown(AdminDataFileLoaderBean.java:338)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.SecurityInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataFileLoaderBean_$$_javassist_seam_12.viewDiscreteVariableBreakdown(AdminDataFileLoaderBean_$$_javassist_seam_12.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 54 more
14:01:20,907 WARNING [lifecycle] #{adminDataFileLoader.viewDiscreteVariableBreakdown}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

javax.faces.FacesException: #{adminDataFileLoader.viewDiscreteVariableBreakdown}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:296)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:253)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:466)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'countCoalesce'
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[DOT] DotNode: 'miscollvar0_.VALUE'
          +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'miscollvar0_.COLL_VAR_VALUE_ID'
          \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'value'

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1652)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxy.createQuery(EntityManagerProxy.java:81)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataLoadValidator.refreshDiscreteVariableValues(AdminDataLoadValidator.java:437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataLoadValidator_$$_javassist_seam_16.refreshDiscreteVariableValues(AdminDataLoadValidator_$$_javassist_seam_16.java)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataFileLoaderBean.viewDiscreteVariableBreakdown(AdminDataFileLoaderBean.java:338)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.security.SecurityInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.myprograms.ece.admindatafileloader.AdminDataFileLoaderBean_$$_javassist_seam_12.viewDiscreteVariableBreakdown(AdminDataFileLoaderBean_$$_javassist_seam_12.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 54 more
```

My new dialect class

```
package org.myprograms.ece.pi;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.engine.Mapping;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class CustomECEOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

  public CustomECEOracle10gDialect() {
    super();

    registerFunction( 
      "countCoalesce", 
      new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.LONG, "count(coalesce(?1, 'null'))") {
        public Type getReturnType(Type columnType, Mapping mapping) {
          return Hibernate.LONG;
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

My persistence.xml file

```
<persistence-unit name="ECE">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:/ECEDatasource</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.myprograms.ece.pi.CustomECEOracle10gDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="mySchema"/>
     <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/ECEEntityManagerFactory"/>
     <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
  </properties>
```

My query using the new function

```
Query qyDiscreteVariableValues = entityManager.createQuery(
  " select " +
  "   misCollVariableValue.value as value, " +
  "   countCoalesce(misCollVariableValue.value) as Total " +
  " from " +
  "   MisCollVariableValue misCollVariableValue " +
  " where " +
  "   misCollVariableValue.mdCollVariable = :pMdCollVaraibleId " +
  "   and loadId = :pLoadId " +
  " group by " +
  "   misCollVariableValue.value "
);
```

The generated SQL,

```
select
    miscollvar0_.VALUE as col_0_0_,
    count(miscollvar0_.VALUE) as col_1_0_ 
from
    greesc.MIS_COLL_VARIABLE_VALUE miscollvar0_ 
where
    miscollvar0_.COLL_VARIABLE_ID=?
    and miscollvar0_.LOAD_ID=?
group by
    miscollvar0_.VALUE
```

Comment: couple of questions: Why do you need this? there might be better approaches . Have you tested your query directly and know it to work?

Comment: I need to obtain a count of all distinct values within the database (Eg, A = 22, B = 5, C = 33, null = 11) this includes null values. However when the original query (replace countCoalesec with count) executed the null count is always 0 even when there are null values present within the data. So I added the count(coalesec(x, 'null')) to the generated SQL and the correct value is returned. However HQL will not allow the nesting of coalesec within the count statement so hence the reason I was attempting to register my own function / template.